# Visual Studio 2015 build up for WINE

Tags: wine

Below are the set of errors I am getting when I want to run Visual studio 2015 build on Linux using WINE. Updated WINE to latest version, updated library to have the `.dll's` shown below but still the problem persists.

Kindly help me to resolve them.

```
err:module:import_dll Loading library VCRUNTIME140D.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\home\avinash\project_org\mpegh_3d\RM7_fixed\3DAudio_RM7_ReferenceSoftware_20160525\modules\coreDecoder\make\ConsoleApplication2.exe") failed (error c000007b). err:module:import_dll Library ucrtbased.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\home\avinash\project_org\mpegh_3d\RM7_fixed\3DAudio_RM7_ReferenceSoftware_20160525\modules\coreDecoder\make\ConsoleApplication2.exe") not found err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\home\avinash\project_org\mpegh_3d\RM7_fixed\3DAudio_RM7_ReferenceSoftware_20160525\modules\coreDecoder\make\ConsoleApplication2.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Comment: It doesn't work and there's currently no solution: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32486

Comment: While it's true that there is no solution to run VS2015 under Wine, there are alternatives. You could dual boot or run a VM under VirtualBox with a Windows installation running VS2015.